# Access file in Windows LocalStorage (Metro)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have saved an image file to Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. How do I get the path to that file? I tried:

```
localFolder + "/filename.ext"
```

but it doesn't seem to getting the file.

Comment: Can you show more code what you have tried exactly?

Comment: Have you tried: StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt"); ?

Comment: @Falcon165o ms-appdata:///local/file.ext worked thanks! If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt")
```